# Responsive Toggle menu (for mobile) in js work on local but don't work online

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, toggle

site ba-hit .com
(resize your screen in a low resolution 720px for exemple)

I tried to load the jquery in footer.. in header, everywhere but the menu  don't apears when i click on it.

Here is the code :

```js
$(function() {
  var pull   = $('#push');
   menu   = $('nav ul');
   menuHeight = menu.height();

  $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   menu.slideToggle();
  });

  $(window).resize(function(){
   var w = $(window).width();
   if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
    menu.removeAttr('style');
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<nav class="clearfixx">
       <a href="#" id="push">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Menu</span></a>
    <ul class="clearfixx newmenu">
     <li><a id="thehome" href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
     <li><a id="proj" href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
     <li><a id="loca" href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
     <li><a id="cterm" href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
     <li><a id="deco" href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
     <li><a id="rech" href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
     <li><a id="part" href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
     <li><a id="cont" href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

I'm sure it's a conflict with something, but what?

Answer (score 1):

Note: You should provide the relevant JavaScript snippets too, rather than having us dig through all code in your site trying to find what is going on. You have a LOT of script tags. It's a pain to try to find what you're trying to do. Don't make people dig in your code to find things.

It looks like you have a script that should be triggered when you click the #push element to show the #newmenu element.

You are defining a menu variable by calling $('nav ul') then when #push is clicked it calls the .slideToggle of the $('nav ul') element.

When I debug your page, *at the time of your load function call*, both pull, and menu are **null**. I don't know if some other script on the page is affecting your HTML structure during loading, but your jQuery is returning nulls for those variables when it tries to set the event, and that means no event is firing. The jQuery is fine; something else is effecting those elements or your page structure.

Finally, you are using a NAV tag, which is HTML5, but your DOCTYPE is XHTML (not HTML5).

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, you're right, i will edit and write the javascript code that i'm telling about, but i'm sure that it's an other thing that block the script... 
For the HTML5, i don't put the HTML5 DOCTYPE bucause all the website is not html5, only the menu...

Comment: Anyway do you have an idea of which conflict it is ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found alone a solution...
I add the no conflict jquery before the function..
Like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
```

Hope it will help...
Bye.